# why does my code jump to the catch part?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    String meridiem = "";
    String zero = "";
    boolean errorOccured = false;

    do {

        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter the hour:");
            hour = consoleScanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the minute:");
            minute = consoleScanner.nextInt();
            if (minute <= 9)
                zero = "0";
            System.out.println("Please enter either \"AM\" or \"PM\":");
            meridiem = consoleScanner.nextLine();

            if (hour < 1 || hour > 12) {
                throw new InvalidHourException();
            }
            if (minute < 0 || minute > 59) {
                throw new InvalidMinuteException();
            }
            if (!meridiem.equals("AM") || !meridiem.equals("PM")) {
                throw new InvalidMeridiemException();
            }

        } catch (InvalidHourException hourEx) {
            System.out.println(hourEx.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidMinuteException minuteEx) {
            System.out.println(minuteEx.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidMeridiemException meriEx) {
            System.out.println(meriEx.getMessage());
        }

    } while (errorOccured);

    System.out.println(hour + ":" + zero + minute + meridiem + " is a valid time.");

}
```

}

My output looks like:

Please enter the hour: 1
Please enter the minute: 3
Please enter either "AM" or "PM":
Please enter either AM or PM.
1:03 is a valid time.

I was wondering how come its not letting me setup the AM or PM and just jumping to the exception?

Answer (score 1):

This condition would always throw an exception, since `meridiem` can't be equal to both "AM" and "PM" :

```
        if (!meridiem.equals("AM") || !meridiem.equals("PM")) {
            throw new InvalidMeridiemException();
        }
```

It should be :

```
        if (!meridiem.equals("AM") && !meridiem.equals("PM")) {
            throw new InvalidMeridiemException();
        }
```

Comment: FGITW effect again... :(

Comment: hi isn't || mean or though? So like if its not equal to AM or PM then throw the exception. Can you explain to me in further detail about the && part?

Comment: @elequang `||` means or, so if meridiem is not equal to AM or meridiem is not equal to PM, you throw the exception. The correct condition can also be phrased as `if (!(meridiem.equals("AM") || meridiem.equals("PM")))`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the things that @Eran said, also you must change this

```
meridiem = consoleScanner.nextLine();
```

by

```
meridiem = consoleScanner.next();
```

Cause: nextLine advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped, while next Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

see this for more explanation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html